# ng-bootstrap angular config karma jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, ng-bootstrap

Getting the message

> If 'ngb-xx' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of
>   this module

for every angular bootstrap components that i try

Setup process

```
npm install angular-cli
ng new project 
CD project
npm install 
npm install  --save bootstrap 
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http' ;

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' ;

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

it looks like everything is working with ng-bootstrap and angular

but karma and jasmine keep thowing errors like

> Failed: Template parse errors: 'ngb-tab' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'ngb-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ngb-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>
> ("

ngalert

> Failed: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'dismissible' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'ngb-alert'.
>
> 1. If 'ngb-alert' is an Angular component and it has 'dismissible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ngb-alert' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Looks like i am missing something in the configuration of karma and/or jasmine

Please help
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: you need to add ngalert and ngb-tab to the ngmodule's declarations

Comment: where is your karma code?

Comment: @Aravind karma code added thanks

Comment: @Pascal you added the karma configuration and not the karma code

Comment: @Aravind sorry for being noob where should i look for the karma code are you looking for the tsconfig.spec.json

Comment: you are getting error in the test cases or the code?

Comment: @Aravind Code is working fine on ng serve but not on ng test, i think i have something to add to karma/jasmine config but dont know what

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164166/discussion-between-pascal-and-aravind).

Comment: No. You need to fix your test code. But you didn't post it, so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test is missing the `NgbModule` import, to fix it you should be

- importing the module

  ```
  import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' ;
  ```
- adding it to the TestBed imports

  ```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NgbModule, ...],
      declarations: [...],
      providers: [...]
  });
  ```

Comment: include css as in?

Comment: css file for the jasmine page looks like css is missing